# SpringBoot and MongoDb integration in the Docker

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a SpringBoot application running in the docker and I am using PostgreSQL as a database for this project and the database also running in the docker.

Now, I want to use MongoDb along with PostgreSQL as database to my SpringBoot application.

I added MongoDb info in the docker-compose.yml file and created new Dockerfile and ran the application. After that MongoDb got installed and running in the docker successfully.

I created a api for insertion of a document into the collection. When I hit the api I am getting the error. I think, I am not able to connect to the MongoDb which is running in the docker.

> error:- com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket

I think I have to do configuration in the MongoDb before doing any CRUD operations.

Can anyone please share a detailed configuration of MongoDb with some examples.

Or provide some information which can help me achieve my task.

Thanks.

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
mongodb:
build:
context: mongodb
args:
DOCKER_ARTIFACTORY: ${DOCKER_ARTIFACTORY}
container_name: “mongodb”
image: mongo:6.0.4
restart: always
environment:
- MONGODB_USER=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:-username}
- MONGODB_PASSWORD=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:-password}
ports:
- “27017:27017”
volumes:
- “/mongodata:/data/mongodb”
networks:
- somenetwork
```

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG DOCKER_ARTIFACTORY
FROM ${DOCKER_ARTIFACTORY}mongo:6.0.4
COPY init/mongodbsetup.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongodbsetup.sh
CMD [“mongod”]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the issue and successfully able to connect and able to perform CRUD operations too.

Below are the changes I did.

### 1. docker-compose.yml

```
  mongodb:
    build:
      context: mongodb
      args:
        DOCKER_ARTIFACTORY: ${DOCKER_ARTIFACTORY}
    container_name: mongodb
    hostname: mongodb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=databaseName
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=username
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - /mongodata:/data/mongodb
    networks:
      - somenetwork
```

created below file (filename: mongodbsetup.sh) under **projectFolder/builder/mongodb/init**

```
#!/bin/bash

mongosh <<EOF
use code
EOF
```

created below file (filename: Dockerfile) under **projectFolder/builder/mongodb**

```
ARG DOCKER_ARTIFACTORY
FROM ${DOCKER_ARTIFACTORY}mongo:6.0.4

COPY init/mongodbsetup.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongodbsetup.sh

CMD ["mongod"]
```

In **application.properties** file added below properties

```
#MongoDB configurations
spring.data.mongodb.database=databasename
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://username:password@databaseurlOrIpAddress:27017
```

That's it. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

You can find above configuration of docker file that includes both MongoDB and PostgreSQL configurations.

Comment: I change the docker-compose.yml file as below.
`mongodb:
...
      args:
        DOCKER_ARTIFACTORY: ${DOCKER_ARTIFACTORY}
    container_name: "mongodb"
    image: mongo:6.0.4
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=code
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=postgres
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
...`

Application is running successfully without any errors. When I hit the insert document api I am getting below error.

`org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential...` any solutions?